# Removing rows from a data set with respect to multiple conditions in R

Tags: r

I need to remove rows in my data which satisfy more than one condition

the variables are

```
comorbidity
date_of_comorbidity 
date_of_birth
```

i want to remove the rows where both comorbidity is equal to 10 AND date of comorbidity is less than date of birth

I have tried

```
newdata<-subset(df, !(comorbidity1==10 & date_of_comorbidity<date_of_birth))
```

This seems to remove the observations when it is one or the other

I need it to be only when both of these criteria occur in the same row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
newdata<-subset(df, comorbidity1 !=10 | date_of_comorbidity >= date_of_birth)
```

Comment: This seems to be the same as what I have tried.

I need it to check the date only when the comorbidity=10

Comment: This is strange, I have played around with a simulated dataset, and it worked out fine. If you try subset(df, !(comorbidity1 !=10 | date_of_comorbidity >= date_of_birth)), do you see instances with comorbidity == 10 and date of comorbidity less than date of birth?

Comment: The code above works for me (I can see when comorbidity == 10 and date of comorbidity less than date of birth) but when I try the first bit of code you gave me the number of observations drops by too much?

Answer (score 0):

A similar solution with dplyr is:

```
library(dplyr)

newdata <- df %>% filter(comorbidity1 !=10 & date_of_comorbidity >= date_of_birth)
```